# PHP: Whole HTML page as variable - is there a better way?

Tags: php, html, variables, concatenation

I have a large form, in the end of the form a user is presented with a summary:

```
You have entered:
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>First name</td>
        <td><?php echo $firstname ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Last name</td>
        <td><?php echo $lastname ?></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I first designed the summary page and now the thought came to me that it would be nice to send the user this page as a confirmation e-mail. What I have done now is this:

```
<?php $summarypage = "<table>
        <tr>
            <td>First name</td>
            <td>".$firstname."</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Last name</td>
            <td>".$lastname."</td>
        </tr>
    </table>";
echo $summarypage; ?>
```

For loops I use `$summarypage .= "blabla";` within the loops.

When sending the e-mail I can just take `$summarypage` and attach it to my e-mail body. Beautiful.

Is what I am doing OK? It seems very "not elegant" to me.
Isn't `$summarypage` being rendered totally anew when I call it again in my e-mail - meaning all variables concatenated with it (e.g. `$firstname`) will be called again - performance hog?

Is there some kind of "buffer" I could just write the `$summarypage` variable to, so I have a plain-text variable afterwards? Would `$newsummarypage = string($summarypage)` do the trick?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ignore performance on that level, it won't matter. If the method you show works for you, use it.

An alternative that makes things a bit more readable (because you won't need PHP openers / closers)  is [HEREDOC](http://www.php.net/manual/de/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc):

```
<?php $summarypage = <<<EOT
<table>
 <tr>
  <td>First name</td>
  <td>$firstname</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>Last name</td>
   <td>$lastname</td>
  </tr>
</table>
EOT;
?>
```

Comment: I know about herodoc <<<, but can I work with variables in there? When I do $firstname it just outputs "$firstname". When I do <?php echo $firstname ?> it seems to just not be printed at all.

Comment: @moontear Huh? HEREDOC should replace variables. Are you sure `$firstname` is defined?

Comment: I left heredoc out of my answer, but I agree with @Pekka - it's a much easier way to deal with assigning large strings with other variables added into them.  Check the manual page for heredoc, it's got it's own nuances.  http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc

Comment: Yeah I am sure, but maybe I didn't play with HERODOC enough (I quite like the concept). Should I do `$firstname` or <?php echo $firstname ?>` within the <<<blabla .... blabla;` block?

Comment: Just $firstname.  No PHP commands go inside the heredoc block.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are a bit confused about how strings/variables work in php. A little example might help

```
$s = "hello"; //stores the sequence 'h' 'e' 'l' 'l' 'o' in $s
$s = $s." world";//take the sequence stored in $s add the sequence ' world', 
                 //and store in $s again
echo $s; // prints 'hello world'. That is what $s contains, what $s is

$summary = "<div>".$firstname."</div>"; // take '<div>', lookup what $firstname
                 //contains and add that, then add '</div>' and then store this 
                 //new string thing('<div>Ishtar</div>') in $summary.

echo $summary; //$summary here knows nothing about $firstname, 
               //does not depend on it
```

All variables are evaluated when you use them. (Well, most of the time you use variables *by* evaluating them.)

Comment: A confused fella I am. Thank you, this explains a lot!

Comment: @moontear - You're welcome! Oh, a little disclaimer: note that this is a simplistic view, technically this is not 100% correct. Ah well, so much more to learn :)

Comment: As always... I read somewhere that using "." for concatenation is slower than doing "," - but I guess that only goes for `echo`, which takes multiple parameters.

Comment: @moontear - Slower? You realize that you're talking about **micro** seconds here? Seriously, I couldn't care less and neither should you. Writing code that works is hard enough...

Answer (score 1):

$summarypage is a string, so it's just a bit of data assigned to a variable - a plain-text variable, as you said.  Once the data is assigned to $summarypage, the work is done.  You can happily write it out into pages, emails, databases and text files with no additional performance hits related to $summarypage.

Comment: So, when I do `echo $summarypage` once on the page (all the variables within summarypage are iterated through), then **afterwards** I do a `mail($to, $summarypage)`, so summarypage and all variables need to be evaluated AGAIN even though they didn't change since the last echo - or is the complete variable (with all "inside variables" evaluated) just held in memory? (That would be great)

Comment: The evaluated string is what is stored in memory.  If you assign text into a string, the string is only evaluated at that time.  Using that string again is only recalling the data you stored in it.  No further evaluation is performed.  It's just like a numeric value - assign 1 + 1 to a variable and PHP stores 2, not the equation 1 + 1.  Assign "My name is $myName" to a string and you store "My name is Surreal Dreams".